# Are there formulas to find roots of n-th degree polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots, calculator

I have tried a polynomial equation of 7th degree on WolframAlpha but it didn't give me exact forms. Does this mean there are not general formulas for every polynomial equation and calculators use root-finding algorithms?

Comment: Yes, but not as simple as for degrees $1,2,3$ and $4$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod is this the exact reason why Wolfram does not give me exact roots?

Comment: @Moo I know that quintic equations have a general formula but I am asking for general polynomial equations.

Comment: @Mathrix What is a 'formula' is only defined once you specify a language in which that formula will be written. If you don't, then anything can potentially be a formula. I don't know anything that isn't a formula in some language. $p^{-1}(0)$ is a formula that for any polynomial $p$ gives the solutions of $p(x)=0$. [Durand-Kerner's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) is also a formula that you input an arbitrary polynomial and it gives you the roots.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I may not really know what means what but what I meant is the form like $\sqrt{3}$ not $1.732...$.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to expose you to the diversity that 'formula' can have, before you see Abel's impossibility theorem. That way, after you learn that there are no 'formulas in radicals' you also understand that that theorem is only talking about a very specific type of formula.

Comment: @Moo No, you missed the point. Who said that you can't find it for fifth degree?

Comment: @Moo You better read the comments above. They will be useful to you as well as for Mathrix. Also, you should read further down in the very link that you shared, where it talks about Bring's radical.

Comment: @Moo That you conflate 'closed form solution' and 'formula' with 'formula in radicals', thus quoting Abel's theorem wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The quadratic formula is more famous than its [cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula) and [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) counterparts, but all three are solutions in radicals, and [we can't do the same for higher degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem#Proof).